# Get corresponding values from database after selecting front-end element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggling a bit trying to figure out the logic that I should be using.
The problem is this:

There's a database that holds 'clients', every client gets echo'd in their own container in which their (unique) information is displayed, this works fine.

However, now I want to be able to open an edit modal by clicking on a button within this container. What is a good way to **identify said client by a button click**, make a call to the database to send the client's data to the front-end and open a modal with the data pre-filled into the input boxes.

The part I'm stuck on now is actually getting the unique value of said client by clicking on a button.

Honestly I would appreciate any kind of help.

- Hugo

Comment: try creating the onclick function with dynamic client id
<a style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#roundModal-{{$media->id}}" id="add_round_modal">Client iD</a>

Comment: "identify said client by a button click, make a call to the database to send the client's data to the front-end and open a modal with the data pre-filled into the input boxes" is at least three questions not one

Comment: _The part I'm stuck on now is actually getting the unique value of said client by clicking on a button._ was the actual question I was hoping to get answered, the rest was context. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

The list should be generated starting with an *array of clients*, if you keep a reference to the object that has created the section you should be able to get the whole object:

```js
const clients = [
  {
    name: "John",
    surname: "Doe",
    age: 36
  },
  {
    name: "Foo",
    surname: "Bar",
    age: 25
  },
];

const app = document.querySelector('#app');

const createList = () => {
const UL = document.createElement('ul');
for(let i = 0; i < clients.length; i+=1 ){      
    let li= document.createElement('li');  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(clients[i].name));
    li.onclick = () => console.log(clients[i].name, clients[i].surname, clients[i].age);
    
    UL.appendChild(li);
}

app.appendChild(UL);

}

createList();
```

```html
<div id="app" />
```